# Decoding unsigned byte array (which is short[]) to String in java

Tags: java

I have to read an unsigned 8-bit byte array(value range is 0-255) in java and need to decode it to String.

But in java as byte is 8-bit signed value, java is treating it as short[] (array of short values) instead of byte[]. I am able to cast object to short[] only.

What I need is a way to decode this array to String.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give an example of input and desired output.

Comment: You cannot safely decode without knowing the encoding (or [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), as it's often known) of the byte sequence.  Assuming one byte equals one character is incorrect and will break for the many thousands of characters outside the one-byte range.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have info about encoding. Data is coming from Tibco RV and its type is U8ARRAY. (TibrvMsg.U8ARRAY)

Comment: Are you able to show us a sample of your data?  Pass the short array to [Arrays.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-short:A-), print out the result, and include the output in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you tried the obvious?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final short[] input = {72, 69, 76, 76, 79};

    for (final short character : input) {
        System.out.println((char) character);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some characters are diaplaying as ? and some non readable symbols. only 75% of the text is readable.. Is there a way to fix that?
To be precise, data is coming from Tibco Rv & data type as U8ARRAY.

Comment: One byte ≠ one character.  This blindly assumes the bytes are a one-byte encoding like US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, or Windows-1252.

Comment: @Sanjeev you wrote "What I need is a way to decode this array to String." and this does it - if you don't know whether the bytes are representing a valid character or not, you have to find out or check with the persons writing the system you consume, because you can't see this when looking at the character only.

Comment: @Smutje I agree wat u said but I don't have that information right now. Data seems to be in JSON format, by following the above approach, am able to decode 80% of the data correctly. Rest of the data is non readable

Comment: @Sanjeev "Seems to be" is not the kind of thing you want to hear when talking about decoding and interpretation of unknown text :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    short[] x = {0x45,0x46,0x47};
    byte[] y = {0x45,0x46,0x47};
    System.out.println(new String(y));
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    for(short s : x)
        str.append((char)s);
    System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Output

```
EFG
EFG
```

Comment: What do you think `new String(y)` will do on Windows, where the default Charset is UTF-16LE?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert a unsigned byte to a character like this:

```
   byte unsignedByte = 65;
   char character = (char) unsignedByte;
```

All you have to do now is to create a loop over all your values